# Finding the Fixed point of a equation

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I am completely stuck with finding the fixed point of $g(x)$.
The question i am stuck is below.

$$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}},\qquad n=1,2,\dots$$

This question has two parts. First to find $g(x)$ and then the fixed point of $g(x)$.
It would be great if some can help me in finding the fixed point of $g(x)$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things. 

1. Please just put in the exact phrasing of the original question you're working on. Don't rephrase or paraphrase or whatever. Just include the original question.

2. Please include your own thoughts and any reasonable strategy you've used to attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @AbhijeetVats. I will take care of this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the recursive equation, we have $g(x) = \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{1}{x}$, and to find the fixed point of it, we set $g(x) = x \implies \dfrac{x}{2} +\dfrac{1}{x} = x \implies \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{x}{2} \implies x^2 = 2 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{2}$. Thus we have $2$ fixed points.

Comment: Thank you @WangYeFei.

Comment: Nice to meet you too, Manu. Any time.